# How do I display an arrow next to the blue dot in iOS MapKit

Tags: ios, mapkit

In the Apple Maps app there is a blue arrow pointing in the direction the phone is facing
(marked on the attached screenshot).
I can't find how to do the same in my app using MapKit.

I need the map to be facing north and the blue dot with an arrow, just like in the default mode in the apple Maps app.
I know I can do this by manually drawing an arrow. 
But, since it is already implemented in the Maps app, is there a standard setting that allows to achieve this in MapKit?

[image: Apple Maps screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only way to achieve this is to create it manually, as Apple does not have any exposed API for it yet.

I posted quite a detailed implementation answer on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40808645/4769084

Basically you need to add your own 'blue arrow icon' to the mapView user location view, then track the device's 'heading' to rotate the 'blue arrow icon' appropriately.