# Add directional arrow to MapKit Annotation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit

I'm currently developing a transport app and I can get the direction the unit is moving in, as a degree value.

What I am trying to do is add an arrow to the annotation of where the unit is, to show the direction it is going in.

I have tried using the guide from [iOS 10 heading arrow for MKUserLocation dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39762732/ios-10-heading-arrow-for-mkuserlocation-dot) but I was unable to get it to work with my scenario

Comment: Do you find any leads on this? in swift